# htaccess forward /merch/[all subfolders] to /en-gb/catalog/merch/[all subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

Apologies if this has been answered before. I'm sure it has but I can't find a proper solution anywhere.

I've (foolishly) upgraded from opencart 2 to opencart 4 and annoyingly it's adding `/en-gb/catalog/` to the front of all categories and products. The site has had a load of seo done to it so I'm trying to forward the old addresses to the new ones.

There's only a handful of root categories so I figure if I can get everything within `merchandise` forwarded correctly then all the sub-folders of `merchandise` will also forward the same way and save me a TON of time.

So I'm trying to set up my .htaccess to forward one of the existing root categories, e.g.:

```
domain.com/merchandise/[all subfolders]
```

to

```
domain.com/en-gb/catalog/merchandise/[all subfolders]
```

Here's what I've got but it's not quite working

```
RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*) /en-gb/catalog/merchandise/(.*) [R=301,NC,L]
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a way to do it right?

Comment: The answer you posted (and since deleted) looks correct... is that still not working for you?

Comment: It did, then it didn't, then it did again. It feels if I cough loud enough it'll stop working so I was hoping someone else would have a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^merchandise/(.*)$ /en-gb/catalog/merchandise/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

This rule is "correct", the `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string contains the URL-path captured from the subgroup in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The only additional points that could prevent this from working:

1. This rule must go at the top of the `.htaccess`, *before* any existing rewrites (front-controller pattern). (If you placed this at the end of the file then it would only redirect static assets that might be contained in a `merchandise` subdirectory.)
2. Make sure the browser (and any intermediary) caches are cleared. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic (any "errors" are also cached). Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Other minor points:

1. The `$` at the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is redundant, since the regex `.*` is greedy by default.
2. The `NC` flag is likely redundant unless you specifically need to match mixed case versions of `merchandise`?
3. You could also include `merchandise` in the captured group and avoid repeating this in the *substitution* string (also lessens the chance of typos).

For example, the following is effectively the same, but *shorter*:

```
RewriteRule ^(merchandise/.*) /en-gb/catalog/$1 [R=301,L]
```